# Are magic (and religion) just higher-level science in the DC universe?

Tags: dc, magic

Summing my question into one LONG sentence:

Does magic actually exist in the DC universe or is it — and are spiritual realms such as heaven, hell and purgatory — essentially pocket dimensions that can be explained through science?

Comment: Let me see if I’ve got this right — you’re asking whether magic (and spiritual realms like heaven) exist in the DC universe, or whether they can be explained by science or magic? You’re asking whether magic can be explained by magic?

Comment: If the magic and spiritual realms in the DC universe are just a form of higher level science.

Comment: *"Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."* - Arthur C. Clarke

Comment: @Joe: cool. I’ve edited the question so it says that. (For future reference, you can always edit questions and answers that you post here.)

Comment: It's important to draw a distinction between magic and divinity.  Magic explicitly does.  Divinity (of or relating to actual Divine being(s)) is less clear, and intentionally so.

Comment: In a more general sense than just the DC universe, any story that involves magic is either describing technology so advanced that it looks like magic, or a universe where physics is different than our own and temporarily modifiable by that universe's inhabitants. DC is probably a little of both from what I know of it.

Comment: @Philipp Also, "Any sufficiently advanced magic is indistinguishable from technology" ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is absolutely magic in pretty much every incarnation of the DC Universe.  The magic does typically have laws and rules that non-magicians can understand (or at least ones that Batman can understand to a degree).

[image: Zatanna, sorceress and stage magician]

Zatanna, a member of several incarnations of the Justice League and frequent ally of Batman's is explicitly a magic-user.  She incants spells and can cause effects on the fly.  She doesn't need any prep time (beyond thinking up the words) or to manipulate any controls.  Her powers are strictly magical and cannot have any technological explination (unless she's rewritten such that she does).

[image: Dr Fate, a supremely good sorcerer]

Dr. Fate is another explicitly magical being.  He uses magical artifacts in addition to spells.  While it is possible he could be rewritten as a 'high-tech that looks like magic' character, there's many instances of other high-tech people not believing in magic, testing his abilities, and admitting they aren't tech.

[image: She's got a lasso, you know]

Wonder Woman is perhaps the best instance of a 'magically-powered' DC character.  Depending on the backstory, she was given life by the Greek God Zeus.  Her armor was crafted by Hephestus, blacksmith of Olympus.  She's got powers bestowed upon her by various Olympian deities and has literally punched Hades in the face while he sat upon the throne of the Underworld.

There's more (and more and more and more) characters I could discuss.  Captain Marvel ([his name is not Shazam!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IAmNotShazam)), Solomon Grundy, the first Green Lantern (until a retcon made him use advanced technology in-line with the current Lanterns) many different DC characters are empowered by magic.

But finally, here's a final argument:

[image: Superman vs. 10-year old]

Using magic, a 10-year-old boy is a serious threat to Big Blue.  Note that Superman has fought against high tech.  He's torn tech from the 41st Century apart with his bare hands while it was trying to blast him.  He's fought against the best tech a 5th dimensional imp can turn against him (Mxyzptlk being one of the 'looks like magic, but really tech' guys in the DC Universe).  And Captain Marvel's lightning can floor him.  Captain Marvel's **magical** lightning.

As far as the other part of your question...DC Comics quite wisely stays out of religion as much as possible.  Many creatures in DC, including Wonder Woman, Darkseid, and others have professed belief in higher powers.  Many beings which claim to be gods, Gods, and/or Godly have existed.  Many realms that purport to be divine have been seen.

DC hasn't 'officially' said if any of these things are divine.  There's no way they could do that and not upset a significant number of vocal people.  The closest they've come is when you talk about [Spectre](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Spectre).

Comment: Warning: One of my links is a TV Tropes link.

Comment: ...And if you're reading that comment, it's probably already too late. ;)

Comment: @SystemDown: Got it from Google Image Search, wish I could actually take credit.

Comment: Nit: If you're differentiating between godly powers and magic, WW should be in the former since her powers come from the ancient Greek pantheon.

Comment: @terdon: When deities give powers to mortals (or create beings wholesale) like Wonder Woman, those mortals/creations are magically empowered.  Superman is vulnerable to WW because of this - her punches hurt him more than an equivalent-strength non-magical foe's would.  So deities are magical, but magical is not necessarily divine.

Comment: @Jeff no, magical is not divine but if you allow that divine exists and is distinct from magic, then powers that come from a divine source should be divine. Damn, sorry, I can't believe I'm having this argument :).

Comment: I seem to recall the Swamp Thing went to heaven a few times, and participated in an epic battle against evil itself when it issued forth from the twisted and incomprehensible darkness on the far side of hell. That was shortly after (and during) the Crisis, though, so it's probably been retconned since then.

Answer (score 0):

Magic exists, as do spiritual realms of some kind, but their exact nature is deliberately left ambiguous. Some characters believe that magic and the spiritual realms can be explained through science, but others don't, and each side has evidence to back its claim. It is generally not stated which one is right, nor is it stated how the apparent contradictions could be resolved, so that these sides are left in tension.

Some characters even go the other way, by believing that science is just another form of magic. Many of the magic-is-science folks would be offended by that idea, though.